# Split a column, get the mean of the split columns, and update the result

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I am currently trying to separate a column that contains a range of value (as character) into two numeric columns to compute the mean of them if a row has a range. Then, I want to replace the old column with the updated result one. Actually, there are multiple columns to be done.. I tried to find a way, but it seems challenging to me.

Below is the code that I have tried.. which does not work..

```
test.val <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3), 
                       colA = c("100-150", "200", "300"), 
                       colB = c("15", "20-30", "10"))
test.A <- test.val[, lapply(.SD, function(x){strsplit(x, split = "-")}), .SDcols = c("colA", "colB")]
test.B[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c("colA", "colB")]
```

At the end, I'd like to have the following:

```
   id colA colB
1:  1  125   15
2:  2  200   25
3:  3  300   10
```

Anyone that can help me out?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("colA", "colB")
for(j in cols) {
  tmp <- vapply(strsplit(test.val[[j]], "-"), 
                FUN = function(i) mean(as.numeric(i)), 
                FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
  set(test.val, j = j, value = tmp)
}
test.val
#   id colA colB
#1:  1  125   15
#2:  2  200   25
#3:  3  300   10
```

---

Given a vector

```
x <- c("100-150", "200", "300")
```

the result of `strsplit` is a list of character vectors

```
strsplit(x, "-")
#[[1]]
#[1] "100" "150"

#[[2]]
#[1] "200"

#[[3]]
#[1] "300"
```

We wrap this into `vapply` and calculate the mean for each element after we converted each vector to numeric.

```
vapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)), numeric(1))
# [1] 125 200 300
```

We use this result to replace every column specified in `cols` using `data.table`'s `set` function.

Comment: I am familiar more with data.table than other data structures, and this is a really great answer for me.Thank you!

Comment: another possibility: `test.val[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(as.numeric(strsplit(x,"-")[[1]]))), by=seq_len(test.val[,.N]), .SDcols=colA:colB]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `tidyverse` possibility:

```
test.val %>%
 gather(var, val, -id) %>%
 separate(val, c("val1", "val2"), sep = "-", convert = TRUE) %>%
 mutate(res = rowMeans(.[, 3:4], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 select(-val1, -val2) %>%
 spread(var, res)

  id colA colB
1  1  125   15
2  2  200   25
3  3  300   10
```

In the first step, it transforms the data from wide to long format. Then, it separates the values into two columns. Finally, it computes a row mean and transforms the data back to the original format.

Considering that you may have more than two values per column you want to separate:

```
test.val %>%
 gather(var, val, -id) %>%
 mutate(val = strsplit(val, "-")) %>%
 unnest(val) %>%
 group_by(id, var) %>%
 mutate(res = mean(as.numeric(val))) %>%
 distinct(res) %>%
 spread(var, res)
```

Comment: Thank you @tmfmnk.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.